# Wrong sound in center speaker on an Asrock Ion 330

Tags: 11.10, sound, speakers

After I upgraded my Asrock ion330 to ubuntu 11.10 the center speaker has moved to rear left. This is the output from `aplay -L`:

```
 Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=NVidia
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

I have also edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` with this line:

```
default-sample-channels = 6
```

Do I have to edit the line: default-channel-map = front-left,front-right ??

I have sound in right, left. reverse sound in center and rear left, and no sound i rear right, subwoofer OK.

Restart pulseaudio (and also tried to restart ubuntu). No luck.

I have also selected HDMI 5.1 in audio -> hardware

What has gone wrong ?? It worked like an charm in 10.10 and 11.04

Comment: Problem solved, I found an fix:

Comment: The next two files will fix the wrong channel mapping of multi-channel PCM.

sudo wget pastebin.com/download.php?i=f5f9654bb -O /etc/asound.conf

sudo wget pastebin.com/download.php?i=f2e38265 -O /usr/share/alsa/cards/HDA-Intel.conf

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered by the OP

> The next two files will fix the wrong channel mapping of multi-channel PCM.
>       sudo wget pastebin.com/download.php?i=f5f9654bb -O /etc/asound.conf
>       sudo wget pastebin.com/download.php?i=f2e38265 -O /usr/share/alsa/cards/HDA-Intel.conf

the first file, `/etc/asound.conf` looks like this

```
pcm.!hdmi-remap {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "remap-surround71"
    }
}

pcm.!remap-surround71 {
      type route
      slave.pcm "hw:0,3"
      ttable {
            0.0= 1
            1.1= 1
            2.4= 1
            3.5= 1
            4.2= 1
            5.3= 1
            6.6= 1
            7.7= 1
       }
}
```

The second file, `/usr/share/alsa/cards/HDA-Intel.conf` looks like this

```
#
# Configuration for the Intel HD audio (ICH6/ICH7)
#

<confdir:pcm/front.conf>

HDA-Intel.pcm.front.0 {
@args [ CARD ]
@args.CARD {
    type string
}
type softvol
slave.pcm  "remap-surround71"

control {
    name "PCM Playback Volume"
    card $CARD
}
}   

# default with dmix+softvol & dsnoop
HDA-Intel.pcm.default {
@args [ CARD ]
@args.CARD {
    type string
}

   type asym
    playback.pcm {
            type plug
            slave.pcm {
                    type softvol
                    slave.pcm "remap-surround71"
                    control {
                            name "PCM Playback Volume"
                            card $CARD
                    }
            }
    }

capture.pcm {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type softvol
        slave.pcm {
            @func concat
            strings [ "dsnoop:" $CARD ]
        }
        control {
            name "Digital Capture Volume"
            card $CARD
        }
        min_dB -30.0
        max_dB 30.0
        resolution 121
    }
    # to avoid possible phase inversions with digital mics
    route_policy copy
}
hint.device 0
}

<confdir:pcm/surround40.conf>
<confdir:pcm/surround41.conf>
<confdir:pcm/surround50.conf>
<confdir:pcm/surround51.conf>
<confdir:pcm/surround71.conf>

HDA-Intel.pcm.surround40.0 cards.HDA-Intel.pcm.front.0
HDA-Intel.pcm.surround51.0 cards.HDA-Intel.pcm.front.0
HDA-Intel.pcm.surround71.0 cards.HDA-Intel.pcm.front.0

<confdir:pcm/iec958.conf>

HDA-Intel.pcm.iec958.0 {
@args [ CARD AES0 AES1 AES2 AES3 ]
@args.CARD {
    type string
}
@args.AES0 {
    type integer
}
@args.AES1 {
    type integer
}
@args.AES2 {
    type integer
}
@args.AES3 {
    type integer
}
type asym
playback.pcm {
    type hooks
    slave.pcm {
        type hw
        card $CARD
        device 1
    }
    hooks.0 {
        type ctl_elems
        hook_args [
        {
            name "IEC958 Playback Default"
            lock true
            preserve true
            value [ $AES0 $AES1 $AES2 $AES3 ]
        }
        {
            name "IEC958 Playback Switch"
            lock true
            preserve true
            value true
        }
        ]
    }
}
capture.pcm {
    type hooks
    slave.pcm {
        type hw
        card $CARD
        device 1
    }
    hooks.0 {
        type ctl_elems
        hook_args [
        {
            name "IEC958 Capture Switch"
            lock true
            preserve true
            value true
        }
        ]
    }
}
hint.device 1
}

<confdir:pcm/hdmi.conf>

HDA-Intel.pcm.hdmi.0 {
@args [ CARD AES0 AES1 AES2 AES3 ]
@args.CARD {
    type string
}
@args.AES0 {
    type integer
}
@args.AES1 {
    type integer
}
@args.AES2 {
    type integer
}
@args.AES3 {
    type integer
}
type hooks
slave.pcm {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "remap-surround71"
}
hooks.0 {
    type ctl_elems
    hook_args [
    {
        name "IEC958 Playback Default"
        lock true
        preserve true
        value [ $AES0 $AES1 $AES2 $AES3 ]
    }
    {
        name "IEC958 Playback Switch"
        lock true
        preserve true
        value true
    }
    ]
}
hint.device 3
}

<confdir:pcm/modem.conf>

HDA-Intel.pcm.modem.0 {
@args [ CARD ]
@args.CARD {
    type string
}
type hw
card $CARD
device 6
hint.show off
}
```